# Getopt::Long GetOptions error in option spec

Tags: perl, getopts

I'm getting an error with the following script:

```
my $h="";
my $r="";
my $i="";
my $n="";
my $forks="";
my $global="";
my $v="";

GetOptions ("h" => \$h, #print help
            "r" => \$r, #keep all temp folder
            "i" => \$i, #include additional config file
            "n" => \$n, #do not merge temp files
            "forks=f" => \$forks, #number of forks you want to use
            "global=g" => \$global, #special config line option
             "v" => \$v #verbose option
            );
```

The error is:

> "Error in option spec: global=g".

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 2):

`g` is not one of the supported option argument types.  Using the "string" type, `s`, fixes the error:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my $h="";
my $r="";
my $i="";
my $n="";
my $forks="";
my $global="";
my $v="";

GetOptions ("h" => \$h, #print help
            "r" => \$r, #keep all temp folder
            "i" => \$i, #include additional config file
            "n" => \$n, #do not merge temp files
            "forks=f" => \$forks, #number of forks you want to use
            "global=s" => \$global, #special config line option
             "v" => \$v #verbose option
            );
```

Refer to [Summary of Option Specifications](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Summary-of-Option-Specifications)

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking to specify the short for of the option like `-f` as an alias to `--forks`, you need to put it after a pipe: `"forks|f"`

By the way, it is simpler to provide a hashref to GetOptions instead of individual variables. It will be easier to add new options. And if you need some default values, just put it in the hash before calling `GetOptions`.

When specifying aliases, the hash key is the first alternative for the option.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my %args = ( verbose => 1 ); # say verbose is on by default

GetOptions (\%args,
        "help|h",     #print help
        "r",          #keep all temp folder
        "i",          #include additional config file
        "n",          #do not merge temp files
        "forks|f=i",  #number of forks you want to use
        "global|g=s", #special config line option
         "verbose|v"  #verbose option
        );
print_help() if $args{help};
print "working on $args{forks}" if $args{verbose};
```